# How do you get an angularJS w/typescript project to work on a website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, github-pages

I'm really new to development in general, and I have recently followed through the angular 2.0 tutorial. What I'm wondering is how I would be able to host say the tutorial project online at github pages. I've tried uploading the project to my repository I created for the github page, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? Are you not seeing your work in Github?

Comment: So the github page displays my index.html but it seems to have trouble loading resources. When I try to inspect the page, I see a bunch of "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(not found)". It seems like it can't find any of the node_modules for angular.

Comment: Edit: So I looked at my repo and it seems like the node_modules folder is not in my repo. I tried to commit it into my repo but for some reason, Git won't let me.

Comment: Did you install git bash?

Comment: Git bash is installed. Is it possible that the node_modules folder has too many items (over 100). When I try to manually upload on Github, it says that it's unable to upload the file because there are too many items.

Comment: you shouldn't be trying to upload node_modules directory

Comment: If I don't upload the node_modules directory then how is the program going to find the necessary resources?

Comment: through package.json, read more about that here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

Comment: I have a package.json with the properties that the link you provided said to specify. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: you need to find a workaround, do more reading and try find out what others have done to solve their problems

Answer (score 0):

You can upload and commit an existing file to a GitHub repository. Drag and drop a file to any directory in the file tree, or upload files from the repository's main page.

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click Upload files.
3. Drag and drop the file or folder you'd like to upload to your repository onto the file tree.
4. At the bottom of the page, type a short, meaningful commit message that describes the change you made to the file.
5. Below the commit message fields, decide whether to add your commit to the current branch or to a new branch. If your current branch is master, you should choose to create a new branch for your commit and then create a pull request.
6. Click Commit changes.

Also recommend using Git Bash: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Here are the procedures for uploading with Git Bash: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/